# Reserved words for R data.table column names?

Tags: r, data.table, reserved-words

I'm finding some sharp edges regarding specific column names in data.table.  How can I avoid cutting myself on them? Assume I have a data.table with two columns, 'type' and 'value'.

```
numRows = 100
numTypes = 10
dt = data.table(type=sample(numTypes, numRows, replace=T),
                value=rnorm(numRows))
```

If I want to see quickly calculate the mean for all rows with type==3, this works great:

```
dt[type==3, mean(value)]
# [1] 0.08086124
```

But what if "someone who is not me" came along and decided that 'type' is a poor name for the column, and it is really should be a 'class'?

```
setnames(dt, "type", "class")
```

Now when I try the equivalent operation I get scary error messages:

```
dt[class==3, mean(value)]
# Error in setattr(attr(x, "index"), paste(cols, collapse = "__"), o) : 
#  attempt to set invalid 'class' attribute
```

I this expected behavior (for 1.9.4 on OSX)? I presume it happens because 'class' is a function name in R, and something internal to data.table is interpreting it as such.  Wrapping the i clause in parentheses seems to solve the problem:

```
dt[(class==3), mean(value)]
# [1] 0.08086124
```

But maybe there are cases where this workaround fails too?

Is there a list of column names that are expected to fail in this case?

Can user defined functions or loaded libraries cause the same error?

Is there in general a safer way to do this that I should be using?

Comment: It looks like a familiar bug in 1.9.4. Upgrade or put parentheses around it, like `dt[(class==3), mean(value)]`. By the way, if you can make your example work with just a few rows why wouldn't you? If you must go to 100, please remember to use `set.seed`.

Comment: Sorry if the example was too large.  I came across this issue in the course of answering another question I had open (which it looks like you just migrated to Stats?). I didn't consider 100 to be a large number, since I'd just knocked it down from 1000000.  Not sure why you suggest set.seed ---  what would the number of rows have to do with choice of seed?  Or was your point (correctly) that in the absence of set.seed() the exact numbers are not reproducible?

Comment: "Correctly"? Yes, thanks. The point of `set.seed` in a case like this would be so that folks can confirm that the desired results are achieved. By "why wouldn't you?" I meant to remind you that minimal examples are preferred here on SO... and can think of one reason why in this case: if your example is small enough, it can be printed as part of the question, making it faster for a reader to grasp what you're doing and attempting to do. Hey, that's what I do anyways; go ahead and follow your own judgment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be already fixed. Update your data.table package.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
numRows = 100
numTypes = 10
dt = data.table(type=sample(numTypes, numRows, replace=T),
                value=rnorm(numRows))
setnames(dt,"type","class")
dt[class==3, mean(value)]
# [1] -0.2300146
```